# Subdomain not working on heroku and namecheap for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, subdomain, apartment-gem

I am currently building a SaaS application using rails and I want each branch of the company to have its own subdomain. I use the apartment gem to achieve this and it works great locally but it's a nightmare in production. I can't seem to get any subdomain to work in Heroku.

Namecheap is the domain's registrar. The domain has been redirected successfully to the herokuapp but the sub domain can't seem to resolve unlike the way it works locally.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Works fine now, there was a mistake in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Total guess, but make sure you've got the tld_length configured correctly. That's what burned me the first time between local and Heroku.

Search in page for "tld_length" here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: I have similar problem but i am hosting my app in vps.  On my local machine everything works great but in production when request is made to my subdomain for example somesubdomain.domain.com i received site  not found and in console i see request aborted. Is this problem releted to tld_length or i should change setting in my domain redirection?